# asp.net ChangeAction - simple tutorial question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action) {
if (!IsValid)
throw new ApplicationException("Rule violations prevent saving");
}
```

i am following this tutorial:

http://aspnetmvcbook.s3.amazonaws.com/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf

and am not able to compile the above code. it is in my NerdDinner.Models.Dinner

am i placing it in the wrong location?

here's the class:

```
public partial class Dinner {
public bool IsValid {
get { return (GetRuleViolations().Count() == 0); }
}
public IEnumerable<RuleViolation> GetRuleViolations() {
yield break;
}
partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action) {
if (!IsValid)
throw new ApplicationException("Rule violations prevent saving");
}
}
```

here's the error im getting

```
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'ChangeAction' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

please excuse the beginner's question and please let me know if you need any other details. im almost certain that im missing something fundamental here. can anyone please help with this? just run me through the necessary steps?

Comment: We need to see more of the code, what class contains this method?

Comment: Do you have the .dbml file created, and are you sure you spelled everything the same? :)

Comment: @monkey yeah the dbml is there, anything else im missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referencing `ChangeAction` by its unqualified name, so you have to make its namespace visible from your module:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

If the above gives an error, you probably also should add the `System.Data.Linq` assembly to your project's references.

Comment: For me I need to add System.Data.Linq assembly to project references